# push notification with fcm is not working

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am trying to send a notification to list of tokens returned by the 'getTokens' method which successfully returning an array of tokens. 
but steal, the user cant receive notification.
here is the code :

```
 exports.sendNotification= 
 functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}').onCreate( event => {
 const userId = event.params.uid;
 return getTokens().then(tokens => {    
    if(tokens.length == 0){ 
        event.data.ref.child('Status').set("pending");
    }
    else{
        let payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'Firebase Notification',
                source: 'client call',
                sound: 'default',
                badge: '1'
            },
            data: {
                source: userId,
                action :ACTION_NEW_CHAT_REQUEST
            }
        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
    }
});
});
```

thanks for the help :)

Comment: I'm reading it again and again wondering what steal is.. until I figured it out that it should be still, did you deploy the function? Also use `console.log()` to check what is happening while debugging

Comment: Add code to check the response from `sendToDevice()`.  Example code is in [this Cloud Function sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L67-L82).  Also add some `console.log()` statements to your function to output debug status, e.g. `tokens.length.`